# Horizontal scrolling with mouse wheel/keyboard in Excel 2003?

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-excel, keyboard, mouse, microsoft-office-2003

How can I scroll horizontally in Excel 2003 using the mouse wheel with the keyboard? Operating system is Windows XP.

Comment: how about "SCROLL LOCK" on, and then ARROWS?

Comment: Unfortunately the solutions provided so far are only workarounds, they don't strictly actually answer the question in its current form, although to be fair to those that have provided answers, that's probably because it's not possible in excel (I still have this issue with Excel 2013). I was hoping there might have been an option to allow holding down a modifier key (e.g. shift) whilst operating the scroll wheel.

Comment: "SCROLL LOCK" on, and then [CTRL] + [Cursor Left]|[Right] to scroll a complete page left/right or omitting the [CTRL] for scrolling a single column (but in most cases the scroll-wheel button click mentioned by AdamV helps more)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you press down the scroll wheel on most mice, that shows a centre point on screen and then as you move the mouse left / right / up / down it scrolls away from that point. Move further away to scroll faster.

Answer (score 5):

Try this: Alt + PageUp/PageDown

Answer (score 2):

If this is a laptop, take a look at mouse properties. There is usually an option that allows you to configure horizontal scrolling:

[image]

If this is a desktop, I am sure someone could write some sort of AHK script that when you hold down a key and use the scroll, it does horizontal scroll but by far the easiest way, purchase a new mouse, many have an extra axis that allows you to "tilt" the scroll wheel. I think this is called 3D scroll, they are usually available from mice costing around £15 and up.

Comment: The problem is that the new mice **don't work with Excel** in this way. Excel is broken compared to most other programs in this way.